# Reading a file of integers, getting nothing but zero

Tags: java, file-io

So, in my program I'm supposed to read integers from a text file to make a key-listed array of them. Easy enough, except when I got to read the file I get nothing but zeroes out of it.
The file itself looks like this:

```
10111

86 78 95

20222

81 73 87

30333

71 63 77

40444

62 58 67

50555

51 62 48
```

And the code I'm currently is:

```
    File stuff = new File("TheData.txt");
    int [] temp = new int[36];
    int spine =0;
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(stuff);
        while(sc.hasNextInt()){
                temp[spine++] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("" + temp[spine]);
            }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProgramDriver3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I'm trying to read the numbers into a temporary array of ints so I can sort them into where they're supposed to go (the long ones are student ids, the short ones are test scores). When I try and run the thing, though, all I get is

run:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I'm not entirely certain what's going wrong

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use increment operations inside of other operations. Split them up into multiple lines so you understand exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `spine` as you put values into the array, so when you then print out `temp[spine]`, you're printing the next one, which you haven't filled yet!

Change this

```
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
            temp[spine++] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("" + temp[spine]);
        }
```

to

```
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
            temp[spine] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("" + temp[spine]);
            spine++;
        }
```

Comment: What if he doesn't want to print them out anymore and comments out that line. Then, the increment statement will be commented out and all the values will be stored at index 0.

Comment: @Strikeskids Yes, I'd wondered about that. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the number at the index after you have already incremented it. Change your print statement to print out the index without the increment.

```
System.out.println(temp[spine-1]);
```

Also, you have set a length on your array independent of the input file. I would use a List so that the number of integers in the file does not cause a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException upon reading a file that is too large.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(36);
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(sc.nextInt());
}
System.out.println(list);
```